# Validating JWT token in WSO2 API gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

A 3rd party client application would be generating a JWT token. The JWT is generated without any WSO2 dependancy.

The JWT token will then be passed on to a WSO2 API gateway. I want to validate the JWT token on WSO2 API gateway. I suppose, I would need the certificate to validate the token.

Can you please point me to a reference or provide the instructions on how to go about it ? Do I need to write custom code and do some configuration in api-manager.xml ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to write a custom handler for this. You can refer [this documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Writing+Custom+Handlers).

If you want to integrate this handler to all new APIs you create, you can set your handle to API template in `repository/resources/api_templates/velocity_template.xml`.

Comment: I want to enable the custom handler for certain channels (consumers) only. So, if one of the applications, say, App1invokes the API, then the JWT token generated byApp1 will be validated. Otherwise, if it is from some other application, the WSO2 generated JWT token will be expected (validated). Can you suggest how to determine the application and make the custom handler enabled for a specific app ?